# Clicking edit on review audit shows error message instead of passing the audit

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, review-audits

A few minutes ago, I was given [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2649607) in the first posts queue. I decided to edit the question to make it better. When I clicked edit, it took me to [a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17515540/edit) with an error message saying "This post is deleted and cannot be edited.", making it fairly obvious it was an audit.

To confirm, I went back and pressed downvote, and it gave me the message confirming I had passed an audit. I'm fairly sure this message isn't intentional. Shouldn't it say I passed after clicking edit instead of just showing an error message?

Comment: I just reproduced this exact bug in [this audit](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/20135ׁ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this - might have been a temporary issue with JavaScript.

The code does exactly what you say - if you try to edit and audit, you will pass.